# Upload Data to Oracle DB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> writer: DataFrameWriter

```
 writer
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc_url")
      .option("dbtable", "abc" )
      .option("user", "user")
      .option("password", "XXX")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()
```

> Error: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Comment: Try to use partition information and boundaries when writing to Oracle.

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis How can I pass that information with DataFrameWriter?

Comment: you can try with repartition or partitionBy to specify the number of parallel writers